# ODL controller delete pre-configured flow rules in OVS switch, when switch is registered in ODL

Tags: opendaylight, openflow

In time when OVS is registering in opendaylight (first time or after IP connectivity was lost and restored to ODL), each time pre-configured openflow rules on OVS (by ovs-ofctl add-flow) are automatically deleted by ODL. Flush configuration (ovs-vsctl set bridge br0 other_config: enable-flush = false) also not solve this problem.
I found in Google search that ONOS has command to turn-off ability automatically delete rules on the switch. https://groups.google.com/a/onosproject.org/forum/#!topic/onos-dev/ZFAw23uTbWw
May be somebody knows similar command for Opendaylight to turn-off ability automatically delete rules on the switch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What features are you installing? I think with just basic openflowplugin-flow-services you shouldn't see existing flows get removed. Maybe with applications
on top of that (e.g., l2switch, netvirt, etc) they could be proactively
doing this.

Comment: Hi. Yes I am using l2switch feature.
Here is list of all features started on ODL:
features-restconf
features-openflowplugin
features-dluxapps
features-dlux
features-l2switch
features-mdsal
features-netconf

Comment: oh, for sure l2switch will clean the flows. it's goal is to simulate spanning tree.

Comment: But how to configure Opendaylight to turn-off ability automatically delete rules on the ovs switch? Is there some solution for it, except remove l2switch?

Comment: as far as I can remember (l2switch has been a stale project for quite some time now) there was no config knob to disable that part of it's functionality. There are some config changes you can make, but I don't think any of them will help. Here is the dev guide:

https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/l2switch-developer-guide.html